# Editing Multiline Strings in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, selenium, replace

Pretty new to Python here. I am running selenium web driver in order to query some info from a website (only accessible from my organization, yes SQL queries would be much better but this is what I have working at the moment). I am using Selenium's `.text` method to retrieve text from a table and I `print(XXX.text)`, this returns something like this.

```
XXX.pdf
[Remove]
XXX.pdf
[Remove]
etc...
```

The question is I would like to remove, the `[Remove]` so that I am left with something like:

```
XXX.pdf
XXX.pdf
```

or even better

```
XXX.pdf, XXX.pdf
```

This is what I have tried so far which has not worked.

```
dataElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('''blah blah blah''')                                             
datasheets = str(dataElement.text)
datasheets.replace('[Remove]','')
print(datasheets)
```

Python 3.5
Selenium 2

Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [26]: data = '''\
    ...: XXX.pdf
    ...: [Remove]
    ...: XXX.pdf
    ...: [Remove]\
    ...: '''

In [27]: def func(string, rep):
    ...:     return ', '.join([x for x in string.split('\n') if x != rep])
    ...: 

In [28]: func(data, '[Remove]')
Out[28]: 'XXX.pdf, XXX.pdf'
```

You can use something like this.

Comment: I am not sure how to utilize this code. I tried running this exact code which gave syntax error. I tried deleting the ins and outs as well as the bracketed numbers and upon printing the string "data" I received a string exactly as inputted. What am I missing?

Comment: worked like a charm, if I could up vote your answer I would.

Answer (score 2):

What did it print in result? Maybe You forget something.

`dataElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('''blah blah blah''')

datasheets = str(dataElement.text)
datasheets = datasheets.replace('[Remove]','')
print(datasheets)`

Comment: It printed my first code snippet, both before and after my attempt to remove the unwanted string portions

Comment: @JohnKulick this is because .replace method doesn't change Your string, it just return new string with replaced parts, but You don't assign it to some variable.
You need to write it like:
`dataElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('''blah blah blah''')`                                         
`datasheets = str(dataElement.text)`
`datasheets = datasheets.replace('[Remove]','')`
`print(datasheets)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
l = s.split('[Remove]')
s = ', '.join(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this to parse your output.

```
dataElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("blah blah blah")
#I don't know what type is this one, but I asume it's a iterable. 

removes = Set(["[remove]","[remove1]", "[remove2]"])
#You can have a set of the strings you want to remove
for data in dataElement:
#for every unit in this iterable variable we'll do the next lines
    if str(data) in removes == False:
    #if something it is not actually in the set of unwanted stuff.                          
        print(str(data))
        #this is your useful output
        #whatever you wanna do to the filtered output.
    else:
        #this is the stuff you don't want to use, the [remove] ones
```

I hope this gives you a hint. Greetings.